# How to use the replicate method in Lotus Notes for a POP account

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

Has anyone managed to use the [**replicate method**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/pref_trace_connection_t.html) in Lotus Notes?

I am trying to get Lotus notes 7 to get new emails by running the below method using the Domino Interop in C#.

```
replicated = db.Replicate("popgmail");
```

The `popgmail` is a connection which has been setup in Lotus Notes and I am hoping it downloads new emails from my GMail account using the POP protocol.

However, I am not even sure if Lotus Notes can replicate from something other than a domino server?

If so, what should I put in the `Destination server address` in the `Connections` section of Lotus Notes? Here is a [**screenshot**](http://i39.tinypic.com/1zfsyag.jpg).

I appreciate any help in this very niche topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the connection is set up (described in the Lotus Notes help) you can set op the replicator task for fecthing mail. The replication task can be scheduled and will connect to the pop server.

The email(s) will be placed in the mail file and can be fecthed form there.

Comment: I am trying to replicate or I should say get new emails from my pop account programatically. I can already perform replications via the Lotus Notes interface. Do you know how I can replicate my gmail accont via POP using C#?

Comment: Why not let the client handle the fetching of the email through scheduled replication? I do not know if the client replication can be initated throug C#.

Comment: the reason is because I am building an application and I need to search through new emails. The scheduler can only get emails once every minute (smallest duration) which means its possible my application has to wait for a minute before it can search through new emails. Having read some more docs - its becoming more and more likely that the replicate method can only be used with a domino server and not a pop account.

Comment: Yes, the replicate method will only replicate the application with the server

Comment: Is the aplication only available on client or also on a server? There are some options to fetch the mail throug a server task.

Comment: The application is only available on the clients computer and once the emails are found (which are on gmail) I open them with Lotus Notes.

Comment: Then it is a 2 step process, the client needs to fetch the mail through the replication task. Unless the replication task can be started through C# you are stuck with the replication interval. And as far as I know that cannot be done with standard lotus

Comment: I was afraid of that - I guess this application is going to be semi-automatic - oh dear! Thanks for your help Jasper.